# MySQL : Error Code: 3548. There's no spatial reference system with SRID 1498173264

Tags: mysql, gis

I am trying to run a mysql query below:

```
select *
from geo
where st_distance_sphere(Point(-118.2842557, 34.0676834), `geometry`) <= 1609
```

and get an error: `Error Code: 3548. There's no spatial reference system with SRID 1498173264.`

```
MySQL Engine version
8.0.27
```

My table structure is like:

```
CREATE TABLE `geo` (`id` int, 
                    `geometry` text,
                    spatialdata GEOMETRY);

INSERT INTO `geo` (id, geometry)

VALUES 

(2, 'POLYGON ((-118.282067 34.067679, -118.281555 34.067458, -118.281467 34.067419, -118.280624 34.067055, -118.279672 34.066689, -118.279376 34.066558, -118.279233 34.066489, -118.279098 34.066409, -118.278879 34.066251, -118.278047 34.065631, -118.276573 34.067943, -118.276505 34.06805, -118.275848 34.069081, -118.275294 34.069984, -118.274929 34.070554, -118.273876 34.072198, -118.27485 34.072519, -118.2753 34.072711, -118.275707 34.072889, -118.276615 34.073286, -118.27752 34.073681, -118.277735 34.073343, -118.277791 34.073256, -118.278056 34.072844, -118.278522 34.072117, -118.278988 34.071389, -118.279463 34.070648, -118.280081 34.070915, -118.280249 34.070772, -118.281158 34.06934, -118.282183 34.06773, -118.282067 34.067679))') 

(3, 'POLYGON ((-118.555285 34.362201, -118.555219 34.361998, -118.554778 34.360634, -118.554424 34.359603, -118.553965 34.358659, -118.553921 34.358567, -118.553439 34.357795, -118.552339 34.356615, -118.55166 34.356, -118.551612 34.355999, -118.551194 34.355994, -118.549745 34.354685, -118.548745 34.353768, -118.547909 34.353045, -118.547195 34.352502, -118.546862 34.3523, -118.545641 34.351656, -118.543184 34.350706, -118.542851 34.350577, -118.542381 34.350396, -118.542073 34.350288, -118.542008 34.350252, -118.539649 34.349332, -118.53605 34.347959, -118.535769 34.34785, -118.535125 34.347599, -118.534338 34.347228, -118.533434 34.346728, -118.532705 34.346214, -118.532041 34.345665, -118.531035 34.344554, -118.530628 34.344145, -118.530238 34.343806, -118.529486 34.343184, -118.528729 34.342756, -118.528053 34.342392, -118.527135 34.342008, -118.526355 34.341728, -118.52598 34.341644, -118.524945 34.341434, -118.523048 34.341227, -118.522788 34.341195, -118.521972 34.341063, -118.520987 34.340846, -118.52024 34.340662, -118.519549 34.340425, -118.518682 34.340007, -118.517922 34.33964, -118.517862 34.339612, -118.517141 34.339279, -118.516271 34.338841, -118.514968 34.33821, -118.514134 34.337806, -118.513566 34.337526, -118.512981 34.337237, -118.512383 34.336832, -118.512047 34.336584, -118.511511 34.33623, -118.511235 34.336052, -118.510177 34.335397, -118.509312 34.33482, -118.509297 34.334807, -118.508874 34.334455, -118.508688 34.334258, -118.508467 34.334022, -118.508341 34.33389, -118.508001 34.334146, -118.507788 34.334306, -118.507766 34.334322, -118.507725 34.334368, -118.507716 34.334377, -118.507672 34.334405, -118.507629 34.334435, -118.507525 34.334504, -118.507444 34.334564, -118.507364 34.334625, -118.507274 34.334693, -118.50723 34.334726, -118.507098 34.334825, -118.506869 34.334998, -118.506832 34.335026, -118.506637 34.335173, -118.506612 34.335191, -118.506514 34.335262, -118.506455 34.335308, -118.506396 34.335355, -118.506346 34.335393, -118.506004 34.335651, -118.505766 34.335831, -118.504007 34.337157, -118.50408 34.337281, -118.504095 34.337306, -118.504293 34.337511, -118.504534 34.337705, -118.504802 34.337886, -118.505113 34.338061, -118.50549 34.338208, -118.50577 34.338306, -118.506451 34.338544, -118.50662 34.338603, -118.506795 34.338661, -118.506944 34.338711, -118.507221 34.338802, -118.507541 34.338908, -118.507584 34.338922, -118.507655 34.338946, -118.508014 34.339116, -118.508238 34.339267, -118.50835 34.339342, -118.508671 34.33959, -118.508848 34.339785, -118.508998 34.340005, -118.509112 34.340239, -118.50921 34.340505, -118.50941 34.341288, -118.509444 34.341422, -118.509452 34.341455, -118.50973 34.342602, -118.509865 34.343126, -118.510004 34.343667, -118.510189 34.344455, -118.510262 34.34481, -118.510276 34.34504, -118.51026 34.345371, -118.510211 34.345662, -118.510098 34.346009, -118.509945 34.346321, -118.509799 34.346554, -118.509298 34.34722, -118.509253 34.347281, -118.508975 34.34766, -118.508934 34.347715, -118.508673 34.348174, -118.508438 34.348649, -118.508233 34.349267, -118.508156 34.349578, -118.508118 34.349733, -118.50806 34.350197, -118.50806 34.350747, -118.508099 34.351257, -118.508288 34.352505, -118.508287 34.353582, -118.508201 34.354367, -118.507916 34.356055, -118.507822 34.356613, -118.507796 34.356747, -118.507702 34.357234, -118.50762 34.357593, -118.507411 34.358367, -118.507276 34.358785, -118.507189 34.358874, -118.507008 34.359371, -118.506958 34.359648, -118.506924 34.359985, -118.506928 34.360195, -118.506964 34.360888, -118.506977 34.361142, -118.507002 34.361509, -118.507007 34.361581, -118.507097 34.361847, -118.507132 34.362394, -118.507133 34.362472, -118.507135 34.362584, -118.50714 34.362752, -118.507146 34.362964, -118.507073 34.36319, -118.507053 34.363521, -118.507029 34.363792, -118.506999 34.363962, -118.506927 34.364264, -118.506852 34.364572, -118.506794 34.364785, -118.506782 34.364968, -118.506705 34.365148, -118.506528 34.365481, -118.506325 34.365771, -118.506268 34.365851, -118.506795 34.366019, -118.507274 34.366207, -118.507576 34.366365, -118.507943 34.366558, -118.508006 34.366596, -118.508271 34.366758, -118.508796 34.367078, -118.508906 34.367147, -118.509405 34.367455, -118.509957 34.367795, -118.510023 34.367835, -118.510495 34.368121, -118.510658 34.368226, -118.510686 34.368244, -118.510906 34.368385, -118.511282 34.368627, -118.511373 34.368685, -118.511539 34.368788, -118.512044 34.369102, -118.512099 34.369137, -118.512221 34.369213, -118.512529 34.3694, -118.513119 34.369759, -118.51331 34.369879, -118.514054 34.370345, -118.514073 34.370356, -118.514201 34.370431, -118.514405 34.370557, -118.514744 34.370766, -118.514942 34.370887, -118.515141 34.371011, -118.515721 34.371375, -118.516361 34.371762, -118.516555 34.371885, -118.516796 34.372031, -118.517262 34.372313, -118.517487 34.37245, -118.51772 34.372594, -118.517957 34.372742, -118.518128 34.372848, -118.518184 34.372881, -118.518582 34.373121, -118.518847 34.373239, -118.518881 34.373254, -118.519202 34.373396, -118.519553 34.373552, -118.520225 34.373845, -118.520735 34.374067, -118.521184 34.374259, -118.521522 34.374403, -118.521871 34.374553, -118.521996 34.374607, -118.522891 34.374994, -118.523268 34.375161, -118.523397 34.375218, -118.523683 34.375338, -118.523938 34.375445, -118.524107 34.375515, -118.524534 34.375691, -118.524708 34.375763, -118.525182 34.375979, -118.525717 34.376223, -118.525988 34.376392, -118.526089 34.376472, -118.526295 34.376497, -118.526425 34.376527, -118.52666 34.376626, -118.526869 34.376681, -118.527547 34.376969, -118.52777 34.377063, -118.528044 34.37718, -118.529011 34.377589, -118.529427 34.377766, -118.529979 34.378014, -118.530416 34.37821, -118.530488 34.378241, -118.530966 34.378445, -118.53115 34.378524, -118.531275 34.378579, -118.531646 34.378743, -118.531935 34.378868, -118.532104 34.379027, -118.532158 34.379094, -118.532357 34.379368, -118.532552 34.379644, -118.532768 34.37995, -118.53279 34.379981, -118.532949 34.380186, -118.53316 34.380163, -118.53392 34.380114, -118.534117 34.380105, -118.534723 34.380077, -118.534871 34.38007, -118.535799 34.38001, -118.536569 34.379962, -118.537387 34.379909, -118.537611 34.379894, -118.538054 34.379867, -118.538373 34.379848, -118.538877 34.37982, -118.539027 34.379812, -118.539138 34.379804, -118.539239 34.379797, -118.539475 34.379779, -118.539811 34.379754, -118.540602 34.379708, -118.540775 34.379698, -118.540878 34.379692, -118.541868 34.379625, -118.542443 34.379595, -118.542935 34.37957, -118.543308 34.379549, -118.543654 34.379529, -118.544072 34.379506, -118.54425 34.379495, -118.545853 34.379401, -118.545999 34.379392, -118.546854 34.379343, -118.546937 34.379338, -118.546908 34.378931, -118.546899 34.37881, -118.546863 34.378387, -118.546818 34.377853, -118.546808 34.377745, -118.54672 34.376693, -118.546441 34.376683, -118.545898 34.376701, -118.545604 34.37671, -118.544716 34.376767, -118.543927 34.376816, -118.543348 34.376852, -118.54303 34.376871, -118.542202 34.376923, -118.542159 34.376414, -118.542123 34.376003, -118.542102 34.375756, -118.542072 34.375405, -118.542064 34.375313, -118.542037 34.374991, -118.54202 34.374748, -118.541918 34.373244, -118.541903 34.373018, -118.541882 34.372882, -118.541839 34.372597, -118.541828 34.372474, -118.541793 34.372086, -118.541772 34.371818, -118.541768 34.371779, -118.541737 34.371384, -118.541717 34.371136, -118.541698 34.370912, -118.541683 34.370712, -118.541627 34.37, -118.541586 34.369472, -118.541216 34.36949, -118.540862 34.369516, -118.54053 34.369539, -118.539582 34.369607, -118.539536 34.369252, -118.539514 34.369081, -118.539416 34.368151, -118.539402 34.368015, -118.539376 34.36767, -118.539325 34.366997, -118.539411 34.36638, -118.539512 34.366032, -118.539652 34.365769, -118.539888 34.365403, -118.540355 34.364918, -118.540463 34.36483, -118.540978 34.364411, -118.541279 34.364274, -118.541541 34.364154, -118.542173 34.363957, -118.542619 34.363867, -118.543167 34.36384, -118.543837 34.363827, -118.544191 34.363809, -118.544366 34.363801, -118.544637 34.363749, -118.545047 34.363635, -118.545407 34.363523, -118.54568 34.363438, -118.546353 34.363341, -118.546751 34.363336, -118.54717 34.363379, -118.547452 34.363447, -118.547804 34.36354, -118.548195 34.363684, -118.548368 34.363775, -118.548788 34.363998, -118.549112 34.364163, -118.549475 34.364348, -118.54973 34.364436, -118.550081 34.364558, -118.55067 34.364655, -118.551088 34.364666, -118.551612 34.364639, -118.552072 34.364557, -118.552728 34.364315, -118.552845 34.36423, -118.553457 34.36379, -118.553665 34.36364, -118.554027 34.36338, -118.554169 34.363247, -118.554228 34.363192, -118.554695 34.362754, -118.555039 34.362431, -118.555241 34.362243, -118.555285 34.362201))')
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=12ba2b0bfcb6e04fee7361cb85496569

What SRID should I use? and how do I set it in MySQL? I am not explicitly setting SRID.

When I try to set -

```
ALTER TABLE geo ADD geom Polygon;

UPDATE geo SET geom = Polygon(geometry)
```

I get an error,

```
Error Code: 1367. Illegal non geometric '`geo`' value found during parsing
```